# Multithreading within a thread lock

Tags: c#, multithreading, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I am working on speeding up the execution of some processes that publish a bulk set of records (Mostly in the millions) to Elasticsearch. In my C# code I have already implemented a multi-threaded solution using Dataflow as scaffolded below:

```
var fetchRecords = new TransformBlock<?, ?>(() => { ... });
var sendRecordsToElastic = new ActionBlock<List<?>>(records => sendBulkRequest(records));

fetchRecords.LinkTo(sendRecordsToElastic, { PropogateCompletion = true });

fetchRecords.Post("Start");
```

And then the send bulk request call I want to implement:

```
public IBulkResponse sendBulkRequest(List<?> records)
{
    lock(SomeStaticObject)
    {
       // Execute several new threads to send records in bulk
    }
}
```

My question for *you* is on the practicality for executing additional threads within a lock that exists as part of a Dataflow pipeline.

Is this ok? Could I see any potential hiccups in performance, execution, cache/memory misses, etc?

Any insight would be gladly accepted.

Comment: Don't use `lock` with TPL DataFlow.  It defeats the purpose.   TPL DataFlow has built-in concurreny throttling and protection without having to resort to `lock`

Comment: @Fabjan incorrect

Comment: @Stephn_R I'm assuming that your goal is to make sure that sendBulkRequest is executed only by one thread but some operations inside of it are execute in parallel by multiple threads. Is that correct ?

Comment: That is exactly my goal @Fabjan

Comment: @Stephn_R have you seen the `BulkAll()` method that accepts a lazily constructed `IEnumerable<T>` documents and sends concurrent bulk requests with retry semantics? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/3e58310d6c29a35d5568923480f86856bfb9675b/src/Nest/Document/Multiple/BulkAll/ElasticClient-BulkAll.cs and the tests https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/cd8ea82730b7d557e6725079da2342f0be6b130b/src/Tests/Document/Multiple/BulkAll/BulkAllApiTests.cs

Comment: I have not Russ but I am currently using the BulkDescriptor method of preparing bulk orders

Comment: Might save some time in implementing concurrent bulk with TPL dataflow. Here's an example usage: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example/blob/5.x-codecomplete-netcore/src/NuSearch.Indexer/Program.cs#L126-L145

Comment: @RussCam can you submit your suggestion as the solution? This was EXACTLY what I was looking for. My execution times have now decreased by ten-fold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `BulkAll` here, which implements the observable pattern to make concurrent bulk requests to Elasticsearch. Here's an example

```
void Main()
{   
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
    var indexName = "bulk-index";

    if (client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
        client.DeleteIndex(indexName);

    client.CreateIndex(indexName, c => c
        .Settings(s => s
            .NumberOfShards(3)
            .NumberOfReplicas(0)
        )
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<DeviceStatus>(p => p.AutoMap())
        )
    );

    var size = 500;

    // set up the observable
    var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(GetDeviceStatus(), b => b
        .Index(indexName)
        .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
        .RefreshOnCompleted()
        .Size(size)
    );

    var countdownEvent = new CountdownEvent(1);

    Exception exception = null;

    // set up an observer. Delegates passed are:
    // 1. onNext
    // 2. onError
    // 3. onCompleted
    var bulkAllObserver = new BulkAllObserver(
        response => Console.WriteLine($"Indexed {response.Page * size} with {response.Retries} retries"),
        ex => 
        {
            // capture exception for throwing outside Observer.
            // You may decide to do something different here
            exception = ex;
            countdownEvent.Signal();
        },
        () => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finished");
            countdownEvent.Signal();
        });

    // subscribe to the observable          
    bulkAllObservable.Subscribe(bulkAllObserver);

    // wait indefinitely for it to finish. May want to put a
    // max timeout on this  
    countdownEvent.Wait();

    if (exception != null) 
    {
        throw exception;
    }
}

// lazily enumerated collection
private static IEnumerable<DeviceStatus> GetDeviceStatus()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < DocumentCount; i++)
        yield return new DeviceStatus(i); 
}

private const int DocumentCount = 20000;

public class DeviceStatus
{
    public DeviceStatus(int id) => Id = id;
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

If you don't need to do anything special in the observer, you can use the `.Wait()` method on the observable

```
var bulkAllObservable = client.BulkAll(GetDeviceStatus(), b => b
    .Index(indexName)
    .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
    .RefreshOnCompleted()
    .Size(size)
)
.Wait(
    TimeSpan.FromHours(1), 
    response => Console.WriteLine($"Indexed {response.Page * size} with {response.Retries} retries")
);
```

There are observable methods for `BulkAll`, `ScrollAll` and `Reindex` (although there is `ReindexOnServer` which reindexes within Elasticsearch and maps to [the Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) - the `Reindex` method predates this)

Comment: A little over the top but this will do haha

Comment: Will help other people find it. Need to document these better :)