# Elasticsearch BulkAll with NEST: Maximum capacity exceeded

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I'm using the following code to bulkindex documents. It works for everything except my Product model, but only when I try to index more than a few documents. If I do only 1 document it works fine. If I do 10, it fails. My Product model is not very complex, but it does have some nested documents with infinite self-referencing loops, but I did add ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore to handle it.

```
public bool BulkIndex<T>(IEnumerable<T> items) where T : class
        {
            var waitHandle = new CountdownEvent(1);
            var bulkAll = _client.BulkAll(items, b => b
                .BackOffRetries(2)
                .BackOffTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
                .RefreshOnCompleted(true)
                .MaxDegreeOfParallelism(4)
                .Size(100)
                .Index(typeof(T).Name.ToLower())
            );

            bulkAll.Subscribe(new BulkAllObserver(
                onNext: (b) => { Console.Write("."); },
                onError: (e) => { throw e; },
                onCompleted: () => waitHandle.Signal()
            ));
            waitHandle.Wait();
            return true;
        }




        new JsonNetSerializer(builtInSerializer, connectionSettings, () => new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        }))
```

Comment: I also get Elasticsearch.Net.UnexpectedElasticsearchClientException: 'Stream was too long.'  I am only trying to index 14 documents. Like I said, there are infinite self-referenced nested documents, but I thought that ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore should take care of that?

Comment: Can you show a small but complete example that demonstrates what you're seeing? It may be the case that there's an error in the configuration setup. Also, `onError: (e) => { throw e; }` needs to capture the thrown exception in a variable initialized in the outer scope, otherwise it will be swallowed. For example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/48237898/1831